# Evaluating polynomials?

Tags: math, computer-science

Why does evaluating polynomials with n points using the Fast Fourier Transform take O(n log n) time? I am specifically talking about implementing a divide and conquer algorithm that divides the polynomial A(x) into its even powers and odd powers and then uses recursion.

Comment: Why was this voted to be closed?

Comment: The recursion reduces the problem from size N to two problems of size N/2 and O(N) processing. So it is T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n), which is the same complexity as mergesort, O(n log n). Is this enough to you?

Comment: Without divide and conquer each evaluation takes O(n) time. You are evaluating n points, therefore the total time is O(n) * (n) = O(n^2). With divide and conquer you divide the number of points by half (since  +- n is used) but each evaluation still takes O(n) time. O(n) * (n/2) = O(n^2). What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The recursive solution divides the problem of size N into 2 problems of size N/2, then divides each of _those_ into 2 problems, each of size N/4, and so on, with the ultimate result being log(n) problems, each of size 1.

Comment: If you are interested in reading a little more, Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms (at least the second edition) covers it in detail.

Comment: You should look into the Master theorem if you want to understand the complexity of this kind of recursive algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let T(n) be time used by the FFT algorithm to evaluate a polynomial of degree n at n points.

The algorithm splits

A(x)=xB(x^2)+C(x^2),

i.e. into two polynomials: odd and even coefficients. For example: 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 9x + 7 is split into x(3x^2 + 9) + (2x^2 + 7).

Originally you wanted to compute 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 9x + 7 at points a,b,c,d.

Now you want to compute 3x+9 and 2x+7 at points a<sup>2</sup>, b<sup>2</sup>, c<sup>2</sup>, d<sup>2</sup>. Later you will combine that to get values of 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 7 at a,b,c,d.

The crucial idea: since you use roots of unity, **half of the values in a<sup>2</sup>, b<sup>2</sup>, c<sup>2</sup>, d<sup>2</sup> are the same**. Suppose that a<sup>2</sup>=c<sup>2</sup> and b<sup>2</sup>=d<sup>2</sup>.

So you need to compute 3x+2 and 2x+7 at points a<sup>2</sup>, b<sup>2</sup>.

This means you reduced an instance of size N into two instances of size N/2 and O(N) postprocessing.

FFT repeats this process recursively. This is the same recursion equation as for mergesort, which is O(N log N) complexity.

Comment: I also recommend checking "Introduction to Algorithms" (by Cormen et al.), which is a clear exposition of many algorithms.